# How to print the XML data using foreach function

Tags: xml, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, xml-parsing

How to print the XML data using foreach in laravel 5.6 function please suggest any solutions

here attached my XML data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <interface-response> <tldlist> <tld> <tld>co.uk</tld> </tld> <tld> <tld>eu</tld> </tld> <tld> <tld>live</tld> </tld> <tld> <tld></tld> </tld> <tldcount>4</tldcount> </tldlist> <Command>GETTLDLIST</Command> <APIType>API</APIType> <Language>eng</Language> <ErrCount>0</ErrCount> <ResponseCount>0</ResponseCount> <MinPeriod></MinPeriod> <MaxPeriod>10</MaxPeriod> <Server>SJL1VWRESELL_T</Server> <Site>eNom</Site> <IsLockable></IsLockable> <IsRealTimeTLD></IsRealTimeTLD> <TimeDifference>+0.00</TimeDifference> <ExecTime>0.000</ExecTime> <Done>true</Done> <TrackingKey>20caefc5-035d-4a3d-8bbe-2743ea99ea8b</TrackingKey> <RequestDateTime>5/3/2018 3:02:01 AM</RequestDateTime> <debug><![CDATA[]]></debug> </interface-response>
```

please suggest any solution to print the XML data in my blade view

Comment: use a parser to make it easier to output, for example  -  https://github.com/orchestral/parser

Comment: I was stored my XML data into one variable. But this package was convert the XML file to an json array.please suggest me some other solution

Comment: As far as I can see it coverts it into an array (php array), if its out putting json then use json_encode() see here http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php.  Ultimatley this should make it easier section off and output your data.

Comment: What do you want at the end? An array, a json, plain text...?

Comment: I need to convert xml data to json array

Answer (score 0):

I created a Laravel package to simplify parsing xml:

https://github.com/mtownsend5512/xml-to-array

```
$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<interface-response>
  <tldlist>
    <tld>
      <tld>co.uk</tld>
    </tld>
    <tld>
      <tld>eu</tld>
    </tld>
    <tld>
      <tld>live</tld>
    </tld>
    <tld>
      <tld></tld>
    </tld>
    <tldcount>4</tldcount>
  </tldlist>
  <Command>GETTLDLIST</Command>
  <APIType>API</APIType>
  <Language>eng</Language>
  <ErrCount>0</ErrCount>
  <ResponseCount>0</ResponseCount>
  <MinPeriod></MinPeriod>
  <MaxPeriod>10</MaxPeriod>
  <Server>SJL1VWRESELL_T</Server>
  <Site>eNom</Site>
  <IsLockable></IsLockable>
  <IsRealTimeTLD></IsRealTimeTLD>
  <TimeDifference>+0.00</TimeDifference>
  <ExecTime>0.000</ExecTime>
  <Done>true</Done>
  <TrackingKey>20caefc5-035d-4a3d-8bbe-2743ea99ea8b</TrackingKey>
  <RequestDateTime>5/3/2018 3:02:01 AM</RequestDateTime>
  <debug>
    <![CDATA[]]>
  </debug>
</interface-response>
XML;
```

With it, you could convert it using the global helper:

```
xml_to_array($xml);
```

Or the class

```
// At the top of your controller:
use Mtownsend/XmlToArray/XmlToArray;

// Then in your code:
XmlToArray::convert($xml);
```

Now you'll have an array:

```
array:18 [▼
  "tldlist" => array:2 [▼
    "tld" => array:4 [▼
      0 => array:1 [▼
        "tld" => "co.uk"
      ]
      1 => array:1 [▼
        "tld" => "eu"
      ]
      2 => array:1 [▼
        "tld" => "live"
      ]
      3 => array:1 [▼
        "tld" => []
      ]
    ]
    "tldcount" => "4"
  ]
  "Command" => "GETTLDLIST"
  "APIType" => "API"
  "Language" => "eng"
  "ErrCount" => "0"
  "ResponseCount" => "0"
  "MinPeriod" => []
  "MaxPeriod" => "10"
  "Server" => "SJL1VWRESELL_T"
  "Site" => "eNom"
  "IsLockable" => []
  "IsRealTimeTLD" => []
  "TimeDifference" => "+0.00"
  "ExecTime" => "0.000"
  "Done" => "true"
  "TrackingKey" => "20caefc5-035d-4a3d-8bbe-2743ea99ea8b"
  "RequestDateTime" => "5/3/2018 3:02:01 AM"
  "debug" => []
]
```

Then send the converted xml to your view:

```
return view('your-view')->with(['xml' => $xml]);
```

Then just loop over whatever data you want in your view.